# LocalBusiness Schema - difference between @id and @url

Tags: seo, schema.org, local-seo

We include the localBusiness data across all pages on our ecommerce site.

What values should be set for id and url on different pages e.g.

1. example.com/about-us
2. example.com/shop

```
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "localBusiness",
      "@id": "http://example.com/current-page",
      "name": "Ecommerce Shop",
      "url": "http://www.example.com/"
    }
```

Should id be based on the current url or should it be id?

Answer (score 1):

Structured data operates at the page level. **[Google's perspective](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies#relevance)**:

> **Relevance**
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the page content.

and

> **Location**
>
> Put the structured data on the page that it describes, unless specified otherwise > by the documentation.

Therefore, the link must point to the page the content of which is presented in structured data.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an id as a global url based identifier for the specific entity. It can be any url you chose but is typically based on the official url where the entity is found with maybe an extra anchor to indicate which entity on the page.

As Nikant motioned, Google currently only thinks at the page level. They don't connect entities across pages by their id. So, with regard to Google the only real use for ids is to connect entities within a single page. Two entities with the same id get merged which lets you define entities in different parts of the page and have them reference each other.

Google just removed id from it's LocalBusiness guidelines. Probably just to simplify things by removing something that is not required.

url is a way to indicate another page which is the official page for an entity. In this case it should exist as a real page. This is more likely to be of use to Google as a way to connect an entity with a page.

Answer (score 0):

**Local Business Schema**

[How to add structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)

**@id**
A unique URL for a specific branch. It cannot be changed after assignment. Google Search treats URLs as an opaque command, so there is no need to include a working link. If the business has multiple branches, a unique @id must be used for each branch.

https://g.page/supdnipro

https://g.page/sup-station-2

https://g.page/sup-station-3

Answer (score 0):

i found this explanation: URL, required
Globally unique ID of the specific business location in the form of a URL. The ID should be stable and unchanging over time. Google Search treats the URL as an opaque string and it does not have to be a working link. If the business has multiple locations, make sure the @id is unique for each location.

So as g.page links are turned off and they was public, we have a CID (company ID) link that is unique and they work from the beginning, i make them in pleper:

Acceptable links to Google :

https://maps.google.com/?cid=194604053573767737
https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A6%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9E/@43.2115343,27.9121908,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x2b35f5b0d1d9239
http://www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&cid=194604053573767737
http://www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39&fid=0x40a4540b44631ff5:0x2b35f5b0d1d9239
https://www.google.com/search?q=some+Listing+name&ludocid=194604053573767737

Acceptable variants for CID / FID :

194604053573767737
0x2b35f5b0d1d9239
0x40a4540b44631ff5:0x2b35f5b0d1d9239
4657940321976655861:194604053573767737

and i think the url from site which can be changed in time it`s a bad idea, they are saying it mustn`t be a working url, i wana try for 2 different deps in one town to try url to local page and url to google map cid link